# How to count the number of dashes between any two alphabetical characters?

Tags: python, string

If we have a string of alphabetical characters and some dashes, and we want to count the number of dashes between any two alphabetic characters in this string. what is the easiest way to do this?

Example:

Input: `a--bc---d-k`

output: `2031`

This means that there are 2 dashes between a and b, 0 dash between b and c, 3 dashes between c and d and 1 dash between d and k

what is a good way to find this output list in python?

Comment: You can simply try it with for-loop.

Comment: @BoseongChoi Yes, I definitely tried for loop but I gut confused, could you please explain more?

Comment: @Ch3steR I considered that we do not have such an input.

Comment: So both `a-b-c` and `a-----------b` shall become the same output `11`?

Comment: Those are hyphens, not dashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution with regex:

```py
import re

x = 'a--bc---d-k'

results = [
    len(m) for m in
    re.findall('(?<=[a-z])-*(?=[a-z])', x)
]
print(results)
print(''.join(str(r) for r in results))
```

output:

```py
[2, 0, 3, 1]
2031
```

---

Solution with brute force loop logic:

```py
x = 'a--bc---d-k'

count = 0
results = []
for c in x:
    if c == '-':
        count += 1
    else:
        results.append(count)
        count = 0
results = results[1:]  # cut off first length
print(results)
```

output:

```py
[2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I assume the `f` in front of the pattern is a typo? You don't need to create a raw string without backslashes. Also no need for capture group =). Nice answer through

Comment: @JvdV Good point for `f`, thanks. I was using f-string, but I dropped that part while I'm improving the answer, but I forgot removing `f`. I updated my answer. No need capture group also right :)

Comment: @Tim No. `count` is only appended at `results` when `c != '-'` is encountered. If `x` ends with `-`, last `count` will be ignored.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a very simple solution like this:

```
import re

s = 'a--bc---d-k'
# Create a list of dash strings.
dashes = re.split('[a-z]', s)[1:-1]
# Measure the length of each dash string in the list and join as a string.
results = ''.join([str(len(i)) for i in dashes])
```

#### Output:

'2031'

Answer (score 2):

If you input may also begin with a dash, you could use this:

```
def count_dashes(string):
    all_counts = []
    dash_count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == "-":
            dash_count += 1
        else:
            all_counts.append(dash_count)
            dash_count = 0
    return all_counts
```

But if your input always starts with a letter, you may not like the 0 that's always at the head of the list.

If you need the output as a string of ints, then you could add this:

```
def count_dashes(string):
    all_counts = []
    dash_count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == "-":
            dash_count += 1
        else:
            all_counts.append(dash_count)
            dash_count = 0
    return "".join([str(number) for number in all_counts])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple loop approach:

```
myinput = 'a--bc---d-k'
output = []
output_count = -1
for elem in myinput:
  if elem == '-':
    output[output_count] = output[output_count]+1
  else:
    output.append(0)
    output_count += 1

print(output)
```